# Return recursive array/object as flattened object type in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, recursion

I'm trying to write a function that takes a recursive object/array where each node has a "name", and optionally, "children". I would like to then have a function which takes this recursive structure and return a type-safe object where the recursively occurring "name"s are the keys, and the node is the values; so it would error out for you during compile time if you tried to access a key that didn't exist.

So far I was able to get the top-level names recognized this way (names "a" and "b") so that `flat` would be recognized as `Record<"a" | "b", RouteConfigItem<"a" | "b">>`.

```
type RouteConfigItem<Keys> = {
    name: Keys;
    path: string;
    children?: Array<RouteConfigItem<Keys>>;
}

type RouteConfig<Keys> = RouteConfigItem<Keys>[];

function getFlat<Keys>(routeConfig: RouteConfig<Keys>): Record<Keys, RouteConfigItem<Keys>> {
    // Implementation doesn't matter.
    return routeConfig as Record<Keys, RouteConfigItem<Keys>>;
}

const flat = getFlat([{
    name: 'a',
    path: 'a',
}, {
    name: 'b',
    path: 'b',
    children: [{
        name: 'c',
        path: 'c',
    }]
}] as const);
```

But how could I make it also see the non-top-level names as well? Only caring about the types, not the implementation in the body of `getFlat()`, **I would like for `flat` to be recognized as** `Record<"a" | "b" | "c", RouteConfigItem<"a" | "b" | "c">>`.

By the way, the code example seemed to work for me in my WebStorm, but does not seem to work in typescriptlang.org/play, so I didn't include such a link.

Comment: `children` is always array?

Comment: You are right, it should be an array. I have edited my post. The problem still stands, though.

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBASg9gV2BAwnAdgMwJYHMoC8UA3gLABQUVU6AhgLYQBcUAzsAE7bq4A0UFalDC1gACxbsuPfoOoBjMdgA2AEw4R0AfhYwItVRmUgAghw60QAHnhJUGHLgB8A8gF8A3BQqhIUAKIAHpy08sAA0hAgrDZQEMGaqqywiMhoWHguRDBxCehJJFCKKuqauvqG6MZmFta2aQ6ZUG5yVFqwANoA5HSMXQC6UAA+AcEWYZHRNt3FahroAx3oCPQARhAc-U6tULrdvRADXuQUmAjoYdgYULgQwABiyqKx8cj5yRoGRiApdumOHS2AAoOKl7BlcLoAJTleRwDiqKxBEITKIxGBLFbrTZOfj1cGOFxkSjUAD0pKgAEl6GBlBBGOhgKIrugoIYIKwFsAoPRRMgOAA6HYaYAIDis0F-Rr4WjJWjoEDHFonchw9DsKCYJ7coi3B7aoEdYlCA4sLq0Lq8HYicRmi1W9z8Y3UU1QLqrS3W0QSN0eh1CWaldAsI07E0MZhu+SeklCKg2n1daP+6hufoUNNQWVFDDsKEeIA

Comment: Changed some stuff, have a look

Comment: Perfect, thanks! Write that as an answer, and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've simplified a bit the `RouteConfig` definition:

```
type RouteConfig = {
    name: string, 
    path: string, 
    children?: ReadonlyArray<RouteConfig> 
};
```

Now to extract keys you can:

```
type ExtractKeys<R extends RouteConfig> = R extends { children: ReadonlyArray<RouteConfig> }
    ? R['name'] | ExtractKeys<R['children'][number]>
    : R['name'];
```

And the function signature would be:

```
function getFlat<R extends RouteConfig>(routeConfig: readonly R[]):
    Record<ExtractKeys<R>, RouteConfig> {

    // Implementation doesn't matter.
    return routeConfig as any;
}

const flat = getFlat([{
    name: 'a',
    path: 'a',
}, {
    name: 'b',
    path: 'b',
    children: [{
        name: 'c',
        path: 'c',
    }]
}] as const); // Record<"a" | "b" | "c", RouteConfig>
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBASg9gV2BAwnAdgMwJYHMoC8UA3gLABQUVU6AhgLYQBcUAzsAE7bq4A0F1KGFrAAFi3Zce-StQDGo7ABsAJhwjoA-CxgRaKjEpABBDh1ogAPPCSoMOXAD4KAXwDcFCqEhQAogA9OWjlgAGkIEFZrKAhAjRVWWERkNCw8R0JYGLj0BJIoBWU1DR09A3QjU3MrGxT7dKgXAWpNWABtAHI6Rg6AXSgAHz9A8xDwyOtOwtV1dD629AR6ACMIDl7nWSodTu6IPo9yCkwEdBDsDChcCGAAMSURaNjkXMTauzSnAAoOZI%20HFjqfSGEDtXoASiYzSoujkcA4KksASCYwiURgjl4SVsqQcGTIWygAHoiVAAJL0MBKCCMdDAEQXdBQAwQVhzYBQegiZAcAB00Kg6mACA4TN%20OPq%20FoiVo6BAhyaR3IcPQ7CgmAeHKI1zumq%20bQJgj2LA6tA6MkEwjEJrNMhcWMN1GNUA6y3NAqt4hdbot8kUMxKUANAqNDGYLrk7sJlpEXo6kd9VBcvVc-WlBQw7HBbmJpNh8MRACJaIXBlBC8tS0NC3JC1j3rj0kA)